# MYSQL, query to get sum of different values in a field from group by criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table structure**

```
create table dataList 
(
id int auto_increment primary key ,
field1 char(2),
field2 char(2),
field3 char(2),
field4 char(2),
location_id int ,
sub_locationId int 
)
```

the field1 ,field2, field3, field4 can have 5 distinct values
**'A,B,C,D,E,F'**

Currently i am only able to get count of all the  values
Query

```
SELECT COUNT(field1),COUNT(field2),COUNT(field3),COUNT(field4) FROM 
dataList group by location_id, sub_locationId
```

Is it possible to get the count of number of A's , B's , C's etc  in each field for a particular location and sublocation

### Expected Output

```
Location_id sub_locationId  field1|   Count |  field2| Count  | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
190        |          210 |    A  |     30  |     A  |    20  | 
190        |          210 |    B  |     20  |     B  |     5  | 
190        |          210 |    C  |     10  |     C  |     2  | 
190        |          211 |    A  |     30  |     A  |    24  | 
190        |          211 |    B  |     30  |     B  |    20  |
```

Sample input

insert into dataList(field1,field2,field3,field4,location_id,sub_locationId)
values('A','B','A','B',190,210),
('B','A','B','A',190,210),
('C','A','B','A',190,210),
('A','C','A','C',190,210),
('B','A','B','B',190,210);

Comment: Do you have a sample Input. Can you create a SQL FIddle?

Comment: @Neels : added sample data query

Answer (score 0):

You should just group by all the fields you want the distinct values for:

```
SELECT   location_id, sub_location_id, field1, field2, field3, field4, COUNT(*)
FROM     data_list
GROUP BY location_id, sub_location_id, field1, field2, field3, field4
```

Comment: Group by all fields will not work , as there will be multipe entry for say , filed1 value 'A', because of the all fields in group by

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly ...

You would have to do either separate queries like:

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM 
dataList where field1='A' group by location_id

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM 
dataList  field2='A' group by location_id

...

or in one statement I would do subqueries like:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM dataList where field1='A' group by location_id) as count_field1,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM dataList where field2='A' group by location_id) as count_field2
```